# Design Project to Automatically show a local webpage to all devices connected on local network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, browser, webserver, hotspot

I am doing a design project and need help of expert how to do it

I have to make a webserver on my computer and upload a webpage on that server .
When a new user comes in a network e.g 192.168.1.1 a dynamic ip is assigned to user and a webpage that is saved on my laptop at address 192.168.1.4 should automatically opens up on user device that might be (Windows,Anroid,IOS)

I want guidance urgently as i have 17 days to complete the project i have googled a lot and tried msg* command but unable to send a specific message to all user including anroid on the network .

What I have done so far made a test page and uploaded on xampp server than from WLAN when i connected to 192.168.1.1 network i can open up webpage by entering address
http://192.168.1.4/web1.html
i want this page to automatically open on each device that will be connected to my network 192.168.1.1

Thanks

Comment: Seems you are looking something like a "landing page". Google for that and you will find many ready-made projects for this purpose.

Comment: Can you give some link where i can find similar example i have tried on google 
Is it  landing pages when a user enter a network and page automatically opens up ????

Comment: Have a look at nxFilter. This is a DNS-Based internet filtering tool. What I meant by landing page is called login-page there. Search for the term in the documetation at http://www.nxfilter.org/tutorial.html.

Comment: I have studied nxfilter that doesn`t work on the same system where i have installed xampp but works on different system so how will be that page running on xampp available automatically to all local network users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for, that you want to search for, is "captive portal".

Once you have an AP that supports captive portal, you'll be able to configure it to redirect all new client devices' traffic at your HTTP server machine. If your current AP doesn't support captive portal, either buy one that does, or see if there's an aftermarket firmware distro that supports captive portal, that you can load onto your model of AP. Look at OpenWrt, DD-WRT, Tomato, Gargoyle, etc.

Comment: can u provide a link that gives in detail tutorial of captive portal configuration ??

Comment: i had a querry that page will be displayed automatically or the users have to open a browser and enter some address than it will be redirected to my specified url??

Comment: I have a querry that when captive portal is setup that will be able to send pop-up page to anroid devices also  ???\